# "Google-served ads obscuring content" issue with Admob banners and camera preview?

Tags: admob

Screenshots from Admob from top of the screen where ads are displayed:

[image]

[image]

Not really sure about first screenshot because there is no banner yet (ad wasn't loaded?).

Also what's the issue with the second screenshot? Is it because we can't use banners over camera preview or what? It was working for all other apps with camera preview but this new app is written in Jetpack Compose but UI is the same, so I don't get it.

Does anybody see the real issue here?

Comment: I didn't update anything and requested a review and they didn't find any issue anymore